# Excel NumberFormat for on range not working using c#

Tags: c#, excel, interop, excel-interop

I am trying to format currency column range using this format

> NumberFormat = "$ #,##0.00";

Every time I get this result

> £ 1,016.89

Here is the completed function for setting columns

```
public void SetColumns(List<ReportColumn> columns)
{
    try
    {
        int row = 9;
        int index = 10;
        int count = Report.Data.Count - 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < columns.Count; i++)
        {
            switch (columns[i].Type.ToUpperInvariant())
            {
                case ColumnSettingType.Number:
                    {
                        oRange = (Excel.Range)oSheet.Range[oSheet.Cells[index, i + 1], oSheet.Cells[index + count, i + 1]];
                        oRange.NumberFormat = "#,###,###0";
                        oRange.HorizontalAlignment = Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignRight;
                        break;
                    }
                case ColumnSettingType.Currency:
                    {
                        oRange = (Excel.Range)oSheet.Range[oSheet.Cells[index, i + 1], oSheet.Cells[index + count, i + 1]];
                        var format = "$ #,##0.00";
                        oRange.NumberFormat = format; 
                        oRange.HorizontalAlignment = Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignRight;
                        break;
                    }
                case ColumnSettingType.Percentage:
                    {
                        oRange = (Excel.Range)oSheet.Range[oSheet.Cells[index, i + 1], oSheet.Cells[index + count, i + 1]];
                        oRange.NumberFormat = "0.00%";
                        oRange.HorizontalAlignment = Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignRight;
                        break;
                    }
                case ColumnSettingType.Date:
                    {
                        oRange = (Excel.Range)oSheet.Range[oSheet.Cells[index, i + 1], oSheet.Cells[index + count, i + 1]];
                        oRange.NumberFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy";
                        oRange.HorizontalAlignment = Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignRight;
                        break;
                    }
            }
            oSheet.Cells[row, i + 1] = columns[i].ColumnName;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Need help what I am doing wrong aur need to setup some culture with it.

Comment: I assume the issue is that you get the pound symbol instead of dollar sign?  In that case it would seem to be a culture issue and we'd need to see code to advise where you'd need to specify the culture that would give you a dollar sign (though it's strange that it didn't do a period for the thousands separator and a comma for the decimal)

Comment: What code you want to see? 
I want to add symbols dynamically regardless of culture. I have different symbols for report like dollar and euro. I want them to be printed with value, while I am testing this I am facing this issue.

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/modelformatcurrency-symbol-property-excel) is what you're looking for.

Comment: Can you share an example for this

Comment: oRange.NumberFormat.ModelFormatCurrency = "$"; when I set this it gives error saying string doesnot contain a definition for 'ModelFormatCurency'

Comment: That's because `NumberFormat` is a `string`.  The documentation isn't that great, so I'm not seeing where that gets set.  It might be something you have to set at the workbook level.  That's about all I can suggest.

Comment: @juharr: You are right the documentation is very poor for this but the currency symbol can be specified for each individual cell/range (option box when Currency format is set - NumberFormat always seems to be identified with $ regardless of currency symbol) - so it ought to be able to be set on a Range object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the NumberFormat property uses the $ symbol to indicate the cell is in Currency format - that uses the current locale currency symbol as far as I can see.

The actual currency symbol used for the cell/range can be set in the NumberFormatLocal property.

Setting both should display the value as "$ 1,016.89"

```
 var format = "$ #,##0.00";
 oRange.NumberFormat = format;
 oRange.NumberFormatLocal = format;
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch I appreciate that.